# Вернуть значения таблицы в шаблон находящийся внутри шаблона LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

Всем привет!
У меня есть таблица categories из которой нужно вытащить данные в шаблон categories.blade.php, который не используется как самостоятельная страница. Этот шаблон используется только внутри других шаблонов, например home и header.

У меня создан котроллер CategoryController и модель Category. В коде модели только присвоено имя таблицы - categories.
Внутри шаблонов home и header у меня используется @include('categories') в нужном месте.

Код контроллера CategoryController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('categories', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

Код шаблона categories.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category )
<div class="catalog-main-menu__root">
<span class="catalog-main-menu__root-icon" style="background-image: url({{$category->image}});"></span>
<span class="catalog-main-menu__root-title">{{$category->name}}</span>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Код маршрута web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

Я при переходе на страницу home, я получаю ошибку Undefined variable $categories.

Если в маршруте web.php задать прямой переход на шаблон categories, то он отображается без ошибок. Т.е. код представленный мною работает, но только если я напрямую перейду на страницу.

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавлять данные при инклуде нужной view ([including subviews](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews))

```php
@include('categories', ['categories' => $categories])
```

2. Добавлять при рендере ([view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers))

файл: `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;


public function boot()
{
    View::composer('categories', function ($view) {
        $view->with('categories', Category::all());
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Первый вариант выдал такую же ошибку. Второй вариант сработал. Но мне кажется, что так не совсем корректно делать, ведь в таком случае CategoryController абсолютно бесполезен. Может есть более правильный вариант?

Comment: во-первых, первый вариант выдал ошибку потому что сюда `return view('home');` надо добавить данные, аля `return view('home', ['categories' => Category::all()]);`, во-вторых, вы правы, CategoryController  абсолютно бесполезен и не нужен, удалите его. Во втором варианте нет проблем, всё корректно

Comment: А не лучше ли будет создать компонент с категориями и уже его использовать на страницах, где он нужен? `php artisan make:component Categories`

Comment: Правая и левая рука, какая лучше? Надеюсь, намёк понятен

Comment: Не совсем. Ведь, если у меня много вызываемых данных, то внутри AppServiceProvider будет куча кода, а компоненты, как я понимаю, позволяют это дело разбить по частям.

Comment: Что мешает не совать всё в один провайдер?

Comment: Если совать всё в одно место это же нарушение модульности. Так-то можно и в web.php всё засунуть не используя ни контроллеры, ни модели и т.д. Просто хочется научится всё делать правильно , а не лишь бы работало.

Comment: Каким образом то что будет распределено в своих провайдерах нарушает модульность? Правильно это не значит что одно надо использовать вместо другого, это взаимозаменяемые инструменты, что угодно использовать можно, главное как это использовать.